# Does Guice DI create a new WSClient instance everytime

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, playframework, guice, ws-client

I have a Client class that makes an API call to an external vendor. In my controller, I inject the client as follows.

```
@Singleton
class AdsController @Inject()(client: MyClient)(
  implicit ec: ExecutionContext
) extends InjectedController {

  def index = Action.async(json.parse[ClientRequest])  {
     client.send(request.body).map({
       case s: SuccessResponse => Ok(Json.toJson(s))
       ...
     }) 
  }
}
```

The client class looks as follows

```
class MyClient @Inject()(ws: WSClient, appConfig: Configuration)
(implicit ec: ExecutionContext) {...}
```

I wanted to understand two things

1. Does the injector inject a new instance of MyClient for every request?
2. If yes, Does the injector inject a new instance of WSClient and Configuration every time?

If both are yes then injecting configuration unnecessarily creates new instances which won't be a good idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Guice by default always create a new instance. Unless you configured it to reuse the instance by e.g. annotating object as `@singleton` or configuring `Provider` that uses some cache or using `bind` to explicitly point to the instance that should be used when some class is required..

This is a desired behavior, as there are many issues and errors related to using singletons (e.g. it's easier to produce a memory leak with them), so this has to be a conscious, explicit decision of a programmer, who should make sure that it won't bite them.

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted to ensure that a new WSClient is injected every time and a single instance of configuration injected. Your answer would mean that both the Configuration and WSClient new instances are injected every time a request is hit.

Comment: If in your config there is no `@singleton`, `bind` or `Provider` involving `WSClient`, I would assume that there is a new instance every time. (Though you can easily check it - `WSClient` doesn't override `toString` or `hashCode` so by printing them, you should see if value is the same or changes between usages).

Comment: Oops sorry, I missed the Singleton, updating the question. I will try printing hashCode

Comment: I am getting the same hashcode every time for MyClient and for WSClient. Which means WSClient or MyClient is not injected everytime. I am puzzled now, If two concurrent request happens how does they share the same object.

Comment: `WSClient` like everything else in Akka is build around concurrency, and internally it all uses ThreadPools to run tasks. Client returns `Future`/`CompletionStage` so it can be triggered by any number of requests at once and it will just schedule jobs on queue in ThreadPool.

Answer (score 0):

The router in Play is a [singleton](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/6bac5dadfd1879600074de868b7c1432ea96a812/core/play/src/main/scala/play/api/inject/BuiltinModule.scala#L107)

```
@Singleton
class RoutesProvider @Inject() (
    injector: Injector,
    environment: Environment,
    configuration: Configuration,
    httpConfig: HttpConfiguration
) extends Provider[Router] {

...

bind[Router].toProvider[RoutesProvider]
```

which effectively means even if controller class is not annotated with `@Singleton` the injected controller instance is [by default reused](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34867199/5205022) between requests, unless the route is prefixed with `@` operator in the `routes`:

> ...if you prefix a controller with @ ... a new action instantiated per
>   request.

For example, given

```
class MyClient

class HomeController @Inject()(cc: ControllerComponents, client: MyClient) extends AbstractController(cc) {
  def index = Action {
    Ok(s"HomeController identity = ${this.hashCode}\nMyClient identity = ${client.hashCode}")
  }
}
```

and the following `routes` file

```
GET     /                           controllers.HomeController.index
```

different requests always return the same identity despite `HomeController` not being a singleton

```
// request 1
HomeController identity = 409392943
MyClient identity = 475611387

// request 2
HomeController identity = 409392943
MyClient identity = 475611387
```

however if we use `@` operator in the routes file

```
GET     /                           @controllers.HomeController.index
```

then we see identity is changing on each new request:

```
// request 1
HomeController identity = 1249276649
MyClient identity = 1152488919

// request 2
HomeController identity = 41809453
MyClient identity = 213518354
```

Comment: Tried the above routes line with @, the identity doesn't seem to change.

Comment: @Deepak It will not change if `AdsController` is explicitly annotated with `@Singleton`.

Comment: Ahh Got it, One question is this approach fine in case of concurrent requests scenario will cause any problem becaue every request will use the same instance ?

Comment: @Deepak When using singletons the onus is on the programmer to ensure the controller and all its dependencies are thread-safe. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40643080/why-use-singleton-controllers-in-play-2-5

Comment: Great thanks, I wanted to make sure the usage of WSClient as I have written above doesn't cause any problem in a concurrent request processing scenario.